# Schulfrei wegen zu viel Schnee als Substantiv

Tags: single-word-request, compound

Wegen (erwartetem) starken Schneefall blieben diese Woche an ein oder zwei Tagen die Schulen in mehreren Städten und Landkreisen geschlossen und es fand kein Präsenzunterricht statt. Die Schulkinder hatten „schneefrei“ oder auf Englisch einen „snow day“. Wie kann man das unmissverständlich als (zusammengesetztes) Substantiv ausdrücken?

- *Schneefreitag* – *Freitag* mit Schnee?

  - *Schneefrei-Tag*?
- *schneefreier Tag* – ein Tag *ohne* Schnee?
- *Schneetag* – irgendein Tag mit Schnee?

(PS: Anderswo war wegen Glatteis und Eisregen schulfrei, aber das ist für die Frage irrelevant.)

Comment: ein schneefreier Tag ist ein Tag ohne Schnee - zumindest meistens :) Ein Schulfrei-wegen-Schnee-Tag

Comment: Warum reicht Schneefrei nicht aus?

Comment: Um mal die Prämisse anzuzweifeln: Wie kann man irgendetwas unmißverständlich ausdrücken? Englisch *snow day* ist selbst mehrdeutig, es kann auch nur ein Tag mit Schneefall gemeint sein.

Comment: Wie wär es mit der Neubildung *Kältefrei* analog zu *Hitzefrei*?

Comment: @Janka aber es ist nicht frei wegen Kälte. Das korrekte Wort dafür ist schon oben erwähnt und heißt schneefrei. Eng damit verbunden: Glättefrei.

Comment: @Janka *Kältefrei* wäre keine Neubildung. Das Wort gibt es bereits

Answer (score 4):

Analog zu *Hitzefrei* dürfte das in den Kommentaren bereits genannte Substantiv *Schneefrei* einigermaßen klar die gewünschte Bedeutung wiedergeben.

Etwas *unmissverständlich* auszudrücken dürfte selbst unter Zuhilfenahme von Adjektiven und anderen Mitteln zur näheren Erläuterung nur äußerst selten gelingen.

Comment: "Hitzefrei" ist oft auch nur deshalb unmissverständlich und nicht mit "frei von jeglicher Hitze, also kalt" zu verwechseln, weil es meist in einem Kontext wie "Die Schüler haben ..." verwendet wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Richtig. Sehe ich genauso.

Comment: Im Satz „Mittwoch war [s]chneefrei“ sehe ich das Prädikativ doch recht deutlich als Adjektiv, nicht als Substantiv an. Die Frage ist doch letztlich, ob „Mittwoch war (ein) Schneefreitag“ oder „Mittwoch war (ein) Schneetag“ ebenso akzeptabel sind oder ob es eine noch bessere Formulierung gibt.